# trying to change a textbox's input in google slides through a list in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a list of names and email address in a spreadsheet and I also have a Google Slide that has a template of sort of a welcome which looks like this:

[image]

The names in the spreadsheet should change the second textbox (Name) and duplicate the slides based on the list.

I want to, as well, send the name's respective slide to their email (kinda like a personalized welcome email).

But right now, I'm trying first how to change the name (but if you can help me with the sending email part, you're more than welcome to do so.)

Here's my code so far (which is in my spreadsheet):

```
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  // Get the Google Sheet object.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the range of cells containing the names.
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A");

  // Iterate over the range and change the input of the textbox on the slide.
  range.getValues().forEach(function(row) {
    // Get the name from the spreadsheet.
    var name = row[0];

    // Get the Google Slide object.
    var slide = SlidesApp.openById("YOUR_SLIDE_ID");

    // Get the second textbox on the slide.
    var textbox = slide.getShapes()[1];

    // Replace the placeholder text in the textbox with the recipient's name.
    textbox.setText(name);

    // Duplicate the slide.
    var newSlide = slide.duplicate();

    // Add the new slide to the presentation.
    slide.getPresentation().appendSlide(newSlide);
  });
}
```

I'm getting a `TypeError: slide.getShapes` error. And I'm not sure how to correct this. :(

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer by guessing your situation. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your sample Google Slide? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `I'm getting a TypeError: slide.getShapes error.`, when I saw your script, I guessed that an error like `TypeError: slide.getShapes is not a function` might occur. Because Class SlidesApp.Presentation has no method of `getShapes`.
- Also, even when `getShapes()` worked, Class SlidesApp.Shape has no method of `setText`. By this, other error occurs.
- I think that `var slide = SlidesApp.openById("YOUR_SLIDE_ID");` can be moved outside of the loop.
- In your script, 2 new slides are added by `var newSlide = slide.duplicate();` and `slide.getPresentation().appendSlide(newSlide);`.
- In the case of `var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A");`, when the empty rows are existing, those are used as new slides in every loop.

If the 1st slide in the Google Slide is your expected slide and when these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From your showing script, it supposes that your script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet. Also, it is supposed that your 1st slide in Google Slide is the template slide. And the template slide has more than 2 shapes. Please be careful about this.

```js
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById("YOUR_SLIDE_ID");
  var templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  if (templateSlide.getShapes().length < 2) {
    throw new Error("Number of shapes is less than 2.");
  }
  range.getDisplayValues().forEach(([name]) => {
    if (!name) return;
    presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide).getShapes()[1].getText().setText(name);
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, a new slide is copied by using the template slide of the 1st slide. And the text of the 2nd shape is changed to the value of `name`.

#### References:

- [Class Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation)
- [Class Shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettext)

Comment: Thanks for this. It's working great, however, I'm not sure why but it's not reading the supposed textbox. The code is correct, but for some reason, it's editing the 3rd textbox?

Comment: Here's the copy of the slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/12-tcML1PCJS6ndAvQStsT5CFyvdMx6u7FZdkD6L--1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oof, it's all good. It's working. Haha.