# Saving google slides as images and then inserting the image ID/URL into google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am trying to create customized invitations. I have a list of names and email addresses in a google sheets file. The name of the guest is inserted into a google slides file and then saved as a thumbnail which can then be emailed. However, I want the image to also be saved in a specified location on my drive, and I want the image ID/URL for each guest to be inserted in Row C for the corresponding person.

My code before modification.

```
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  var presentationId = "11i9F3qH-xX1c4FGO6cSSAaTGNwTRowk-6W183lntLRA"; // Please set your presentation ID of Google Slide.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // In this case, the active sheet is used. If you want to use the specific sheet, please modify this to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("###Sheet name###")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  range.getDisplayValues().forEach(([name, email]) => {
    if (!name || !email) return;
    var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
    newSlide.getShapes()[0].getText().setText(name);
    presentation.saveAndClose();
    var { contentUrl } = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, newSlide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" });
    
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Invitation to the walima of Ameen to Aqeela", // Please set your email title.
      htmlBody: "Assalamu Alaikum Dear" +" " + name + "." + "\n" + "\n" + "We would love for you to attend the walima of Ameen to Aqeela. Please see the invitation attached",
      inlineImages: { image1: UrlFetchApp.fetch(contentUrl).getBlob() }
    });
    presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  });
}
```

I modified the code as below but it is not able to execute the code citing that there is an error in getting the thumbnail:

```
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate2() {
  var presentationId = "11i9F3qH-xX1c4FGO6cSSAaTGNwTRowk-6W183lntLRA";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];

  range.getDisplayValues().forEach(([name, email]) => {
    if (!name || !email) return;
    var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
    newSlide.getShapes()[0].getText().setText(name);

    // Generate a unique ID for the image (you can use Utilities.getUuid() or any other method)
    var imageId = Utilities.getUuid();

    // Save the image ID in Google Sheets
    var imageIdColumn = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3); // Assuming the image IDs will be stored in column C
    imageIdColumn.setValue(imageId);

   // Get the objectId of the new slide
var newSlideObjectId = newSlide.getObjectId().replace("SLIDES_API", "");

try {
  // Make the API call with the correct objectId
  var { contentUrl } = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, newSlideObjectId, { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" });

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Invitation to the walima of Ameen to Aqeela",
    htmlBody: "Assalamu Alaikum Dear" ...",
    inlineImages: { image1: UrlFetchApp.fetch(contentUrl).getBlob() }
  });
} catch (error) {
  Logger.log("Error getting thumbnail. Slide ID:", newSlideObjectId);
  Logger.log("Error details:", error);
}


  });

  // Close the presentation after all slides are processed
  presentation.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: First, if you are using [a script of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77199051), I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the thumbnail image as an image file and want to put the URL of the created image file in column "C".
- From your showing script, I guessed that you might be using [a script of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77199051).

#### Modification points:

- In your question and showing script, I cannot understand the filename of the created image file, and although you are using `inlineImages`, `image1` is not used in the HTML body. From this situation, I guessed that your expected filename might be the name, also, you might want to attach the image file as an attachment file instead of the inline image.
- In your showing script, unfortunately, the thumbnail image is not created as a file. And, the URL of the file is not retrieved.
  When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your `presentationId` and `folderId`.

```js
function changeSlideTextAndDuplicate() {
  var presentationId = "11i9F3qH-xX1c4FGO6cSSAaTGNwTRowk-6W183lntLRA"; // Please set your presentation ID of Google Slide.
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set your folder ID. The images are saved into this folder.

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // In this case, the active sheet is used. If you want to use the specific sheet, please modify this to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("###Sheet name###")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var templateSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  var values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([name, email, url]) => {
    if (!name || !email) return [""];
    if (name && email && url) return [url];
    var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
    newSlide.getShapes()[0].getText().setText(name);
    presentation.saveAndClose();
    var { contentUrl } = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, newSlide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" });
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(contentUrl).getBlob().setName(name);
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Invitation to the walima of Ameen to Aqeela", // Please set your email title.
      htmlBody: "Assalamu Alaikum Dear" + " " + name + "." + "\n" + "\n" + "We would love for you to attend the walima of Ameen to Aqeela. Please see the invitation attached",
      attachments: [blob]
    });
    presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
    return [folder.createFile(blob).getUrl()];
  });
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the values of `name, email` are valid values, emails are sent with the attachment file, the thumbnail is created as an image file, and the URL of the file is put into column "C".
- In this case, when the values of column "C" have already been existing, the row is skipped. If you want to overwrite, please remove the line of `if (name && email && url) return [url];`.

Comment: Yes you understood me perfectly. The script worked exactly as I hoped it would! The initial answer I used was helpful to me, with the emailing, however I also wanted to have the images saved and access them and this modification solved my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @Tasneem Ghoor Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi again. I notice that when running the script, all the links are only placed in the cell upon the full completion of the script. With the limitation on App script runtime, if the number of images to be generate exceeds the runtime, then no links are pasted in. How can I edit the code such that the links are placed row by row?

Comment: @Tasneem Ghoor About your new question of `With the limitation on App script runtime, if the number of images to be generate exceeds the runtime, then no links are pasted in. How can I edit the code such that the links are placed row by row?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?